# excel - show only tuesdays and thursdays dates of a specific month

Tags: excel

please can you help me and write if there is a way in excel where a column  shows all the Tuesdays and Thursdays dates (format 20-01-2018) of a particular month?

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific, and show what you've tried, if you want some help (and not have your question closed).

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then come back and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52610199/edit) adding sample data, expected output and what you've tried so far.

Comment: i smply need a column that show all the dates of the tusdays and thursdays that are in a month, for example: 02-10-18,04-10-18, 09-10-18....and so on

Answer (score 1):

Not so much to go on but here is my interpretation of an answer:
fill in cell A1 with a date 2018-10-02 that is the first Tuesday in your series.

In cell B1 write =A1+2
In cell C1 write =B1+5

Now mark the cell B1 and C1 and drag them to the right using the small square in your selection.

If you want to make sure it is a Tuesday or Thursday use the function:
=TEXT(A1;"ddd")

Answer (score 0):

Write the first date in `A1` eg. This Tuesday `10/oct/2023`. Make sure to format all the column as a date.

Write `=A1+2` in `A2` you will have Thursday's date.
Write `=A1+7` in `A3` you will have the following Tuesday's date.

Select both (`A2` AND `A3`) and use the lower right corner of the cells (fill handle) to generate the fill of the rest of the list. Then you'll have all Tuesdays and Thursdays.